# How to type a Generic Function in TypeScript with predefined key value?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to type this function in TypeScript and hitting a dead end every time. It’s complaining about using `any` as a type of the passed in d object.

```
const current = (d: any): number => d.currentYear;
```

Basically, it is a function that takes in an object `d` and returns `.curentYear` property value out of it. The shape of the `d` object may change and hence it can be any object. I tried to look into Generic Types and this is the closest I could find:

```
const getProperty = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key];
```

The downside is that I have to pass in the property during the function call:

```
getProperty(d, 'currentYear')
```

Is there any better way to type this function signature?

Comment: not sure why sometimes people on stackoverflow, give down vote without telling the reason. It's really unfair.

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface that has the property you need :

```
interface HasCurrentYear {
    currentYear: number;
}
const current = (d: HasCurrentYear): number => d.currentYear;
```

Then, you can call `current` with any object that has a `currentYear` property :

```
current({currentYear:2021})
```

Answer (score 0):

if your 'd' may change, using extends keyword is better solution.
in this way you guarantee that your d object will have a currentYear prop, no matter what.

```
 interface HasCurrentYear = {
    currentYear: number;
  };
  
  function current<T extends HasCurrentYear>(obj: T) {
    return obj.currentYear;
  }
```

so if you pass a object without cureentYear prop, you will give an error and the good point is that if you pass a object with currentYear and some other props it still works.
also you can wtite it inline

```
 function current<T extends { currentYear: number }>(obj: T) {
    return obj.currentYear;
  }
```